# arabic words from right to left how to append or join them

Tags: mysql, servlets, pdfbox, right-to-left

hi i have display a arabic text in pdf using servlet it will print characters from left to right but i want a word from right to left as a single word came from database not as a single character.I upload icu4j-49_1.jar but its not working.
i also have used PDFTextStriper it will bind character but only in console printing direction left to right.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String relativeWebPath = "/font/arial.ttf";
    String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
    File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);

    System.out.print(file);



 ByteArrayOutputStream output=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 PDDocument document=new PDDocument();
 PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File(absoluteDiskPath));
 PDPage test=new PDPage();
 document.addPage(test);
 PDPageContentStream content=new PDPageContentStream(document, test);
 final String EXAMPLE = "نديم";
 System.out.print(EXAMPLE);

 try{
     con=DBUtility.getConnection();
     stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from login");
     rs=stmt.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()){

         userName=rs.getString("UserName");
         password=rs.getString("Password");

         content.beginText();
         content.newLineAtOffset(50, 680);
         content.setFont(font, 12);
         content.showText(rs.getString("UserName"));
         System.out.print(rs.getString("Password"));
         content.endText();


     }


 }catch(SQLException ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }

 content.close();

PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String Text = textStripper.getText(document);
 System.out.print(Text);

 document.save(output);
 document.close();


 response.setContentType("application/pdf;base64,BASE_64_ENCODED_PDF");

response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"TestReport.pdf\"");
response.getCharacterEncoding();
response.getOutputStream().write(output.toByteArray());



}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "word came from database not as a single character"? Give example please in your question.

Comment: It would be useful to show what is in `rs.getString("UserName")` and what appears in the PDF.

Comment: although it's possible to generate a correct arabic document in PDFBox a better solution might be to take a look at Apache FOP as this provides a high level text processing API based on XSL:FO.
If you need to do it in PDFBox please be aware that a) tex in PDF is stored in presentation not logical order and b) glyphs in arabic text change according to context c) make sure that the font does support arabic glyphs

Comment: ي م  د ن  its came like this i want نديم like this can any one help me please

Comment: first you have to reverse the string as PDF always puts the content from left to right. Second you need to look up the proper joining character for the individual 'letter' to be placed.

Comment: add on to my previous comment. As PDF wouldn't do the word forming for you if you store the strings the result of the reversed string will have ن (u0646) for the start of the word where it should have نـ‎ (uFEE7) as this is the glyph replacement when nūn is at the beginning of the word. You'd need to implement such replacement prior to doing `content.showText()`. 
Now the issue is that when one would extract such text the replacement char is chosen. To handle that you'd need to supply a `ToUnicode` mapping and should provide an `ActualText` property for text extraction and screen readers.

Comment: in addition the GSUB table of the font (if available) can be used for such replacements.

Comment: Maruan Sahyoun Please can you show me example how to map it ? and how we manage each and every unicode character.